# Fluent Assertions: Approximately compare Dictionary values

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dictionary, fluent-assertions

I'm once again having difficulty getting the customisable aspects of FluentAssertions `Should().BeEquivalentTo` to do what I'm after. The current problem is approximately comparing dictionary values. How would I go about getting this test to pass using the `BeEquivalentTo` options:

```cs
[Fact]
public void SomeTest()
{
    var dictOne = new Dictionary<string, double>
    {
        { "a", 1.2345 },
        { "b", 2.4567 },
        { "c", 5.6789 },
        { "s", 3.333 }
    };

    var dictTwo = new Dictionary<string, double>
    {
        { "a", 1.2348 },
        { "b", 2.4561 },
        { "c", 5.679 },
        { "s", 3.333 }
    };

    dictOne.Should().BeEquivalentTo(dictTwo, options => options
        .Using<double>(ctx => ctx.ApproximatelyCompareDouble(1e-2))
        .WhenTypeIs<KeyValuePair<string, double>>()
    );
}
```

`ApproximatelyCompareDouble` works correctly, but I've included it here for completion:

```cs
public static void ApproximatelyCompareDouble(this IAssertionContext<double> ctx, double precision)
{
    var bothNaN = double.IsNaN(ctx.Subject) && double.IsNaN(ctx.Expectation);
    var bothPositiveInf = double.IsPositiveInfinity(ctx.Subject) && double.IsPositiveInfinity(ctx.Expectation);
    var bothNegativeInf = double.IsNegativeInfinity(ctx.Subject) && double.IsNegativeInfinity(ctx.Expectation);
    var withinPrecision = Math.Abs(ctx.Subject - ctx.Expectation) <= precision;

    Execute.Assertion
        .BecauseOf(ctx.Because, ctx.BecauseArgs)
        .ForCondition(bothNaN || bothPositiveInf || bothNegativeInf || withinPrecision)
        .FailWith("Expected {context:double} to be {0} +/- {1} {reason}, but found {2}", ctx.Subject, precision, ctx.Expectation);
}
```

Comment: What if you change the generic type in `WhenTypeIs` to `double`?

Comment: @DennisDoomen I just retried in case I somehow missed that, unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: It's a bug. It seems that something that is supposed to run these custom rules doesn't run for dictionary pairs (yet).

Comment: Ah, ok, well that would explain the difficulty that I was having. Not sure if it is worth you putting your comments as an answer?

Comment: https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/pull/886